# Find Last Row Until Next Highlighted Cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to find a last row until next highlighted cell and clear the range.

`Range("B2").End(xlDown)` won't work, I found something called `xlCellTypeSameFormatConditions` under `SpecialCells` but not sure how this could be applied.

Maybe there is a better method?
The result should clear Range B2:B7 only

[image]

Ok so combining both solution into one I have it like this

```
Private Sub WorkSheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
  If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then

  Dim rngCheck, rngCell As Range

  Set rngCheck = ActiveSheet.Range("B2:B" & Cells(2, 2).End(xlDown).Row)
    For Each rngCell In rngCheck
      If rngCell.Interior.Pattern = xlNone Or rngCell.Value = "" Then rngCell.Value = ""
    Next
  Set rngCheck = Nothing

  End If
End Sub
```

So basically when value in "A1" changes, trigger a clear.
The same code works under `Module` but not with `WorkSheet_Change`

Comment: Color is not data. What made the cell get highlighted? Why not use real data in real cells as indicators and use conditional formatting based on the real data. The real data can then also be used to identify cells for other purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

[image]

```
Sub test()

Dim rng As Range

With Application.FindFormat
    .Clear
    .Interior.Color = vbWhite
End With

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Change to correct sheetname
    Set rng = .Range("B2:B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
    rng.Cells.Replace What:="*", Replacement:="", SearchFormat:=True
End With

End Sub
```

[image]

---

If you want to run the code on a sheet change event try the below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim rng As Range

Debug.Print Target.Address
Application.EnableEvents = False
If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
    With Application.FindFormat
        .Clear
        .Interior.Color = vbWhite
    End With
    Set rng = Range("B2:B" & Cells(2, 2).End(xlDown).Row)
    rng.Cells.Replace What:="*", Replacement:="", SearchFormat:=True
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of Set rng = .Range("B2:B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row) how can I change it to work with End(xlDown)?

Comment: @ggmkp, you could change `Set rng...` with `Set rng = .Range("B2:B" & .Cells(2, 2).End(xlDown).Row)`

Comment: Your code works as is but when I tried to combined the solution into one it doesn't work. I updated my original post of what I'm trying to accomplish

Comment: @ggmkp, But why would you use a loop? Also edited the answer.

Comment: I want to add say 2 instead of deleting the value, I changed the `rng` to `rng.Cells.Value = "2"` but this doesn't seems to work...

Answer (score 1):

Try this, note there is no exception or error handling. This will stop as soon as it hits a highlighted cell no matter what colour, and will not remove non-highlighted cells which are between highlighted cells.

```
Sub MoveToNextHighlightedCell()
  Do Until Not ActiveCell.Interior.Pattern = xlNone Or ActiveCell.Value = ""
    ActiveCell.Value = ""
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
  Loop
End Sub
```

Alternatively use this, it will not stop unless there are missing values. Updated as per comment from @Mikku.

```
Sub MoveToNextHighlightedCell()
  Dim rngCheck, rngCell As Range
  Set rngCheck = ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown))
    For Each rngCell In rngCheck
      If rngCell.Interior.Pattern = xlNone Or rngCell.Value = "" Then rngCell.Value = ""
    Next
  Set rngCheck = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I would suggest not to use the `ActiveCell` and use a defined Range instead as using `ActiveCell` can lead to unwanted results and errors.

Comment: @Mikku yes this is true, not much to go on in terms of use case so I made it simple.

Comment: wow this is a bit complicated I'd thought there would be a much simpler way. but thank you let me test this

Comment: @T4roy 1st option is very risky as it could wipe out other data if used in an actual project. I made some changes to the 2nd option but it doesn't seems to work. I updated the my post to reflect this